# ActiveMQ: "User is not authenticated" error

Tags: authentication, activemq-classic

I'm trying to set up ActiveMQ version 5.10.1 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.1 with a new user which can use the web console (following the instructions in http://activemq.apache.org/web-console.html).

What I have done:

1) Created following entry in users.properties: myUser=myPwd

2) Added the user to the 'publishers' and 'consumers' groups in groups.properties

3) Added the following to jetty-realm.properties to enable access to the web
console: myUser: myPwd, user

4) Added the following in the activemq.xml file under plugins
->authorizationPlugin -> map -> authorizationMap:

```
<authorizationEntries>
  <authorizationEntry queue=">" read="admins" write="admins" admin="admins" />
  <authorizationEntry queue="MYQUEUES.>" read="consumers" write="publishers" admin="admins" />
  <authorizationEntry topic=">" read="admins" write="admins" admin="admins" />
  <authorizationEntry topic="MYQUEUES.>" read="consumers" write="publishers" admin="admins" />
</authorizationEntries>
```

I can log into the console with the new user, but am getting "SecurityException: User is not authenticated" messages in ActiveMQ's log file when, in the web console, I try and click on any of the ActiveMQ queues I have created.

According to the log, the error is occurring when it's creating a bean with name 'queueBrowser' defined in /WEB-INF/webconsole-query.xml.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing jaasAuthenticationPlugin element in activemq.xml.